# Memory efficient way to access a map in c++

Tags: c++

I have recently learnt that accessing a key in map that doesn't exist inserts the key into the map with the default value.

```cpp
map <int, int> m;

m.find(1) == m.end() // true
cout << m[1];
m.find(1) == m.end() // false
```

What is the best way to access value in a map without allocating additional memory in case the key doesn't exist? Is there a cleaner/better alternative to something like below?

```cpp
map <int, int> m;

auto it = m.find(3);

if (it == m.end()) {
   return;
}

const auto& val = it->second;
```

Comment: last version is recommended. You can wrap this into a function which will return optional.

Comment: Maybe `.at(3)`? You haven't defined what is "efficient way".

Comment: .at would work but it throws exception if key is not found, I want to handle the scenario when key is not found.  

Sorry for the unclear phrasing "efficient way" I meant a cleaner or standard way to achieve what I did in second code snippet.

Comment: What is a context? Maybe you are microoptimizng? If you are trying to solve some competitive programing task then issue most probably is your algorithm time complexity not speed of `map`.

Comment: No, I'm not solving any competitive programming question. I just want to know if there's a standard way to do this. The motive is -- I don't want to allocate extra memory in my map.

Comment: your second example is the canonical way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A marginal improvement in syntax is possible in C++17: you can initialize your iterator inside the if-statement's condition:

```
map <int, int> m;

if (auto it = m.find(3); it != m.end())
{
    int val = it->second;
    cout << "Found that value: " << it->first << " -> " << val << '\n';
}
```

This way is maybe better because it limits the scope of `it` and `val` to the if-statement. But maybe this style is too strict — if your code is complex, you may end up with many nested if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out *`find`, then compare with `end()`* is the canonical way to do this. If you're writing this very often, and want to shorten it, you could use this helper `maybe` function:

```
#include <optional>

template<
    template<typename,typename> class C,
    typename K,
    typename V
> std::optional<typename C<K,V>::iterator> maybe(C<K,V> &c, K const &k) {
    auto it = c.find(k);
    return c.end() == it ? std::optional<typename C<K,V>::iterator>() : std::optional(it);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
 
void showcase(
    std::map<int,char> &themap )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ){
        if( auto v = maybe(themap, i) ){
            std::cout << (*v)->second;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind some performance degradation, you can check whether the value exists in the map before accessing it:

```
if (m.contains(3))
{
    int val = m[3];
    cout << "Found it: " << val << '\n';
}
```

This only works in C++20. If you can't use C++20, replace `contains` by `count` — it counts the number of occurrences of your key in the map (which, naturally, can be either 0 or 1 for `map`, but can be greater for `multimap`).

Comment: This is not efficient, because it looks up the key twice.  Better to use `m.find()` by itself and use the returned iterator as needed, that way the key is looked up only once.